# Reading sql query from a json file

Tags: python, sql

I want to fetch the SQL query from a text file and run it in Python program. This is my code:

```
csvfilelist=os.listdir(inputPath)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

for csvfilename in csvfilelist:
         with open(inputPath + csvfilename, 'r') as csvFile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
                for row in reader:

                        '''r = "INSERT INTO Terminate.RAW VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])'''

                        try:
                            result = mycursor.execute(r)
                            mydb.commit()
                        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                            print(err)
                csvFile.close()
```

Comment: what is the issue here ?

Comment: Hi Hasan,

Welcome to StackOverflow. You will get better answers if your question is more specific. What is the problem with your current snippet? What are you trying to get to?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I suppose you mistyped your code. It should be `r = "INSERT INTO Terminate.RAW VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])` without the apexes `'''`, right?

Comment: Thou shalt not use `%` formatting on SQL queries.

Comment: @luca.vercelli I want this query to be read from a text file or config file

Comment: text file, json file, config file? can you explain a bit better? if you are free to choose the format, I suggest you to write a INI config file. If you are not free, please edit your post with your file content.

Comment: config = json.loads(open('C:/Users/mohammeda.rizvi/Desktop/stupidhasan/config.json').read()


This is what i am trying to do...

Comment: So, please post your "config.json".

Comment: {

"sqlSelectQuery":"select * from Terminate.RAW",
"host":"10.144.96.124",
"dbUserName":"jdmssqluser",
"dbPassword":"Jdm$My$qlDev@2019",
"dataBase":"Terminate"
}

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a INI file containing the query

```
[main]
query=INSERT INTO Terminate.RAW VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')
```

you may load it

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('myfile.ini')
query = config['main']['query']
```

and later you can call it with

```
r = query % (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])
```

As pointed out in comments, using "%" in queries is not a good solution, you should bind your variables when executing the query. I don't remember the exact syntax, it's something like

```
r = query
mycursor.execute(r, (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]))
```

**Edit**: sorry, I just read that your file is JSON, not INI. You wrote that in the title, not in the post. If so, you should use the json module instead of configparser module.